# Laravel 5 Register Authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I have some simple/careless issue while register new user, I change the column field : **name to username** from users migration db and also change the name from form register.blade. The issue is when I try to register the required field name must filled.

Comment: can you please add your model & view file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the validator also. Validation script for registration is located at **app\Services\Registrar.php** folder.

Change username in place of name in validator and create.

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

and then in create class.

```
public function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain me why app\Services\Registrar.php accessed by auth controller ?